# Creating A Join In SQL Xampp

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to create a join between my database tables customers and staff. However getting an error:
Can't create table `staff_db`.`customer_orders` (errno: 121 "Duplicate key on write or update").

```sql
CREATE TABLE staff(
staff_id int(12) not null,
staff_name varchar(20),
staff_address varchar(32),
staff_department varchar(20),
PRIMARY KEY (staff_id)
);
```

```sql
CREATE TABLE customers(
customer_id int(12) not null,
customer_name varchar(20),
customer_address varchar(32),
customer_product varchar(25),
staff_id int(12) not null,
FOREIGN KEY staff_fk(staff_id) REFERENCES staff(staff_id),
PRIMARY KEY (customer_id)
);
```

```sql
CREATE TABLE customer_orders(

customer_id int(12) not null,
staff_id int(12) not null,
FOREIGN KEY customer_fk(customer_id) REFERENCES customers(customer_id),
FOREIGN KEY staff_fk(staff_id) REFERENCES staff(staff_id),
PRIMARY KEY (customer_id,staff_id)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your customer_orders table, you named the foreign key " FOREIGN KEY **staff_fk** (staff_id) REFERENCES staff (staff_id) " like the one in your customers table " FOREIGN KEY **staff_fk** (staff_id) REFERENCES staff (staff_id) ". Names must be unique. Change the name to one of the two and your problem will normally be solved.